# create table from 3 tableadapter`s from 2 SQL Server sources and 1 MYSQL source

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I need to create a new dataset from 3 tables and 2 SQL sources, 1 SQL Server and the other MySQL.

- File 1 contains 30 fields with the index on a network number say 'NetworkID'.  (3000 records)
- File 2 contains 8 fields with the index also on a Network number say 'NWK_ID'. (1,900,000 records)
- File 3 contains 3 fields with index on field 'code' (50 records)

In the dataset designer I placed relationships between file 1 'Network' and file 2 'NWK_ID'. And another relationship between file 3 'code' and file 2 'activity'

The reason for the first relationship is to only include records from file 2 that have a record in file 1.

The 2nd relationship is to show the code type based on the activity code!

I just can't figure out how to get these combinded into a query!

This is code being ported over from an Access application! I have no problems doing it there!

```
SELECT 
    MSSQLDB.NetworkID, 
    MySQLDBA.activity, 
    MySQLDBA.cap_plan, 
    MySQLDBA.cap_act, 
    MySQLDBA.cap_var, 
    MySQLDBA.exp_plan, 
    MySQLDBCode.typedef
FROM 
    (MSSQLDB INNER JOIN MySQLDBA ON MSSQLDB.NETWORKID = MySQLDBA.NWK_ID) 
INNER JOIN 
    MySQLDBCode ON MySQLDB.activity = MySQLDBCode.code
```

So now I have a dataset1.xsd file via the dataset designer with 3 tableadapters with relations applied but can't seem to figure out how to build a new table with parts of the 3 adapters!

In case you haven't noticed I'm net to vb.net! I'm using VS2015 as VS2019 has too many bugs!

Thanks

Pete

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you are mixing up two different approaches here. You can add three tables with the appropriate relationships, and three simple queries to populate them, which seems to be the way you have worked so far. Or you can use the join query as the query in the designer, in which case you will get one result table based on that query, which seems to be what you want.

Comment: How do you you define 2 data connections in the query designer?

Comment: In the designer, the connection is set in the tableadapter properties tab. But you have more control over it by setting the TA connection property in code.

Comment: If you had an code example it would really help as I haven<t seen anything in any of the forums, other than people saying you can't do cross table queries!  Which is odd as if you can create 3 tables from different databases , then why not include them in a query!

Comment: Just set the connection for each TA as appropriate. They don't have to be all the same db.

Comment: The connections to each ta are set and they all individually work, I just don't know how to write the query code! I'm in the process of installing a linked server om my mssql side and it should allow me to use a single connection, But if you know how to code a query with 2 connections then I prefer that!

Comment: If you have multiple tables in your dataset then you use multiple queries, each query pulling data for one table. The cross-table operations are then performed by either navigating the relationships in the dataset and/or expression fields. You can use 'where' clauses to make your queries more efficient, returning only the necessary data - depending on your design and the purposes of the dataset.

Comment: Just a heads up, as I had to put this aside to finish up stuff on another project! But I'll get back to it soon!

Comment: I'm trying to make the connection  from the query builder in ACCESS and Visual Studio. In ACCESS Query builder(OR TOAD)  , I end up with an SQL Query statement. I just can't figure out how to do the same in Virtual Studio!  I can use the query builder to add tables from different sources but can't see what to do with it after! I guess what I'm missing is the syntax to use the Query in the first post adapted to using DataTables instead of just tables!

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to "build a new table with parts of the 3 adapters". Fill each table with queries with a WHERE clause to limit it to the data you want. Then at that point you can navigate the relationships to get the data, or use expression fields. But either way you have already pulled your data and you can populate your data objects.

Comment: Sorry my mistake , I should have said I wanted to build a new query and not a new table. I put the 3 table adapters in the query builder and can access data individually in all 3 adapters, I just don't know what the next step is! As I said in Access or Toad when I use a query builder I end up with a WORKING query that I can use in tables,forms reports!  With Visual studio I don't get anything workable or at least that is what I assume. I expected something like the Select clause in my problem description above!  Limiting the data is done via a query with all three tables!  Pete

Comment: Sorry I am really at a loss as to where your confusion lies. I haven't used Access for about 15 years and my memory of it is very hazy, which doesn't help. But I suspect you are trying to apply Access concepts to something to which they don't apply. Once you have built your dataset in the designer, you use it in code, by running the queries in the adapters. Once you have got the data in the tables in the dataset - well, you've got the data, so typically you populate objects, bind a table to a datagridview, or whatever you want.

Comment: If we forget about using the query builder in visual studio as I can't see how to implement it!  How would you create a dataset fro 2 different servers, on a MSSQL and the other a MySQL with an inner join.  Table A   has ID,network,activity_code  as fields and Table B has ID,activity_code,activity_description with and inner join A.activity_code = b.activity_code which will send to the datagridview  2 fields A.Network,Activity_description.  How do you do a cross-server dataset?  I can create an individual  dataset from table A or B no problem.  Show a code sample with Table A and B inner join

Comment: As per my prev, the key thing is that each tableadapter has its own connection property; thus you can populate each datatable within the dataset with a separate query against a different database. From that point, there is nothing special about the fact that the data is from multiple databases - you are just dealing with datatables and datarelations as normal. I can't show you a code sample because we're talking about the designer, not code. This link may help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/relationships-in-datasets?view=vs-2019